# how to separate address (address with comma) string in classic asp?

Tags: string, asp-classic, split

i have a list of address, and at Update: (form submits)

```
name_array = split(request("name"),",")
address_array = split(request("address"),",")
address_2_array = split(request("address_2"),",")
city_array = split(request("city"),",")
prov_array = split(request("prov"),",")
zip_array = split(request("zip"),",")
```

above works perfectly, till someone submits an address (either in address field or address_2 field) like this:
107 Queens Quay W., Suite 254

i tried "replace" but no luck.

any ideas?

Comment: Have different fields for submitting different parts of the address or use `vbCrLf` as the split so instead of relying on comma (`,`) it relies on newline instead (if you are using a multline `<textarea>` for the address input.

Comment: Also, make sure you trim the initial entries and check to see if there are commas on there (`If Instr(trim(request("address")), "," < Len(trim(request("address"))) Then...`).

Comment: I suggest a javascript replace on form submit to replace form fields values with special character (e.g. replacing comma with ##) and recycle the real values again after finishing process using vbscript.